# Unable to send WhatsApp message using chrome driver Python Error: NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

This is my first post here!
I am using Selenium's Chrome Driver to send WhatsApp attachment to some people.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from time import sleep

link="https://wa.me/91xxxxxxxxxx"
phnno="91xxxxxxxxxx"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=f"{os.getcwd()}\\chromedriver.exe")
#driver.get(link)
#button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Share on WhatsApp"]')
#button.click()

driver.get(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phnno}&text&app_absent=0") 
#This above line opens up the sender window in whatsapp

attachbutt=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="clip"]') #This is line 15
#The above line is the one that is giving me the error
attachbutt.click()

sleep(10)

forpdf=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@accept="*"]')

path="C:\\Users\\Deven\\Desktop\\test_file.pdf"

forpdf.send_keys(path) #Attaches the file
sleep(5)

sendbutt=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="send"]')
sendbutt.click()
```

**ERROR:**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56230/devtools/browser/1a8a2adb-37ee-4b0c-bedc-5cfb58559c24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\Python Scripts\Dr Nikhil Prescription App\Prescription Generator\WA-testing.py", line 15, in <module>
    attachbutt=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="clip"]')
  File "C:\Users\Deven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Deven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Deven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Deven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@data-icon="clip"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

PS D:\Coding\Python Scripts\Dr Nikhil Prescription App\Prescription Generator> [16176:15752:0523/212201.236:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:22:01.236] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

It says it is unable to locate the element but I have bene very careful in inspecting the website and then writing the code. Still I wonder why it does not work. Can anyone please help me with what is it that I am doing wrnong? Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a wait / delay before clicking that element.
The simplest solution is to put

```
sleep(5)
```

before

```
attachbutt=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="clip"]')
```

However, it's much better to use expected conditions there. Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

attachbutt = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@data-icon="clip"]')))
```

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, I will try these things! What does that 20 mean? Is it the value of seconds/milliseconds?

Comment: 20 is timeout, how much time to wait until the expected condition is fulfilled. So if the element found to be clickable before that timeout - the method completed instantly and returns the element. If the timeout reached before the expected condition case met - the exception is thrown. You can use any amount of time there of cause

Comment: AFAIK if you create exe file it should be runnable without dependencies. But if you wish to send it as a code that can be read, run and debug you should send the entire project.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Ask moderators / google. I have no idea, really

Comment: I don't know. Please open a new, separate question for this so all the members will see that, maybe some one will help

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't think I have a way to help with that, I'm just a user like you here...

Comment: Solution you shared not working: ```[7268:7252:0524/211325.118:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:13:25.118] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\Python Scripts\Dr Nikhil Prescription App\Prescription Generator\WA-testing.py", line 42, in <module>
    clip=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="clip"]')
ind_element_by_xpath```

Comment: I'm quite sure this is a new, separate issue.

Comment: Getting this error now: ```[5852:10636:0524/212250.821:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [21:22:50.821] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)```